# php include issue - works on one server... not another.. init file?

Tags: php, include, init

php "includes" are working fine on my current production server/site. (shared server)

I am moving this site to a new server and "includes" do not work. Error message:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /home/xxxxx/public_html/publications/abss/myfile.php on line 140
```

In control panel I can set php version from 5.2 to 5.6 and generate init file.  When I look at init file I find no "include" option to enable.

Questions:
Why is there no enable option in php.ini file? (I tried both 5.2 and 5.6 versions)  Can I manually enter?
Does the php.ini file run each time a page is rendered? 
How do I know if php.ini is actually in effect?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can see all information using http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had tryed "allow_url_include" on but didn't work.

However, when I copied my init file from the old server to the new it worked fine.  Not sure why. Didn't do a file compare.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check

```
 phpinfo()
```

to see **allow_url_fopen**" and "**allow_url_include**" are **ON**

If not, you need to set them on OR contact your webmaster or hosting provider to enable allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include in the PHP server configuration.